# Does an arbitrary function preserve arbitrary intersections?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S,T$ be sets and let $\Lambda$ be an index-set. Let $f:S\to T$ and $\{A_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ be a collection of subsets in $S$ (i.e. $A\lambda\subset S$ for all $\lambda\in\Lambda$). Does $f$ satisfy $$f\left[\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda} A_\lambda\right]\subset\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda} f[A_\lambda]\text{ and }f\left[\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda} A_\lambda\right]=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda} f[A_\lambda]?$$

Comment: yes, it is true

Comment: Note that in the first, we need not have equality.

Comment: That's strange. Someone downvoted all the posts on this page.

Answer (score 4):

Sure; the arguments are exactly the same as for the finite case.

Suppose that $x\in\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_\lambda$; then $x\in A_\lambda$ for each $\lambda\in\Lambda$, so $f(x)\in f[A_\lambda]$ for each $\lambda\in\Lambda$, and therefore $f(x)\in\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}f[A_\lambda]$. It follows immediately that

$$f\left[\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_\lambda\right]\subseteq\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}f[A_\lambda]\;.$$

Now suppose that $x\in\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_\lambda$; then there is some $\lambda_0\in\Lambda$ such that $x\in A_{\lambda_0}$. Clearly $f(x)\in f[A_{\lambda_0}]\subseteq\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_\lambda$, so

$$f\left[\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_\lambda\right]\subseteq\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}f[A_\lambda]\;.$$

Conversely, if $y\in\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}f[A_\lambda]$, then $y\in f[A_{\lambda_0}]$ for some $\lambda_0\in\Lambda$, and therefore there is an $x\in A_{\lambda_0}$ such that $f(x)=y$. Clearly $x\in\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_\lambda$, so $f(x)\in f\left[\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_\lambda\right]$, and it follows that

$$f\left[\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_\lambda\right]\supseteq\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}f[A_\lambda]$$ and hence that

$$f\left[\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_\lambda\right]=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}f[A_\lambda]\;.$$

Answer (score 2):

We can do some element-chasing and show this is indeed true:

Suppose $y\in f\left[\bigcap A_\lambda\right]$, then there is some $x\in\bigcap A_\lambda$ such that $f(x)=y$. This means that for all $\lambda$, $x\in A_\lambda$ so $y\in f\left[A_\lambda\right]$ for all $\lambda$, and thus the inclusion holds.

For the union, let $y\in f\left[\bigcup A_\lambda\right]$, then there is some $\lambda$ and $x\in A_\lambda$ such that $y=f(x)$, therefore $y\in f\left[A_\lambda\right]$ and therefore $y\in\bigcup f\left[A_\lambda\right]$. The other direction is similar.

Answer (score 1):

The first holds since $f\left(\bigcap_\lambda A_\lambda\right) \subseteq f(A_\lambda)$
for all $\lambda\in\Lambda$.  This inequality can be strict.

The second is easy to prove. It is true.