# Proof verification: Image of the intersection is the intersection of the images

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

$$ f\left(\bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} A_{\lambda}\right) = \bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} f(A_\lambda)$$

$(\rightarrow)$

Let $b \in f(\bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} A_{\lambda})$
$\rightarrow b=f(a)$ for some $a \in (\bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} A_{\lambda})$.

Since $a \in (\bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} A_{\lambda}) \rightarrow a \in A_{\lambda}$ for some $\lambda \in \wedge$.

Since $b=f(a)$, then $b \in f(A_{\lambda})$ for some $\lambda \in \wedge$.

$\rightarrow b \in \bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} f(A_\lambda)$
$\rightarrow f(\bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} A_{\lambda}) \subset \bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} f(A_\lambda)$.

$(\leftarrow)$

Let $b \in \bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} f(A_\lambda) \rightarrow b \in f(A_\lambda)$ for some $\lambda \in \wedge$

$\rightarrow (*) b=f(a)$ for every $a \in A_\lambda$ and $\lambda \in \wedge$ $\rightarrow b=f(a)$ for every $a \in \bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} A_\lambda$

In order for $(*)$ to be true, $f$ must be $1-1$

$b=f(a)$ for every $a \in \bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} A_\lambda \rightarrow b \in f(\in \bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} A_\lambda)$

Both $(\rightarrow)$ and $(\leftarrow)$ imply that $$ f\left(\bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} A_{\lambda}\right) = \bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} f(A_\lambda)$$

This problem is in Willards, "General Topology." Please let me know if this solution is accurate.

Comment: This problem is in Willards, "General Topology." Which section? Page?

Comment: Please do *not* edit your post in a way that would invalidate the answers. Since you have put a `proof-verification` to your question, please leave it as it was.

Comment: The third problem in 1H

Answer (score 2):

[Added later:]
You miss the point of the original exercise:

> [image]

One should make a correct statement *first*.

The statement in your question is incorrect. (To make it correct, either replace the equal sign with $\subset$ or replace $f$ with $f^{-1}$. Or you need extra assumptions on $f$.) See this question:

[Does an arbitrary function preserve arbitrary intersections?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/170506/9464)

> $$ f\left(\bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} A_{\lambda}\right) = \bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} f(A_\lambda)$$
>
> $(\rightarrow)$ (`OK. You mean` $\subset$`.`)
>
> Let $b \in f(\bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} A_{\lambda})$
>   $\rightarrow b=f(a)$ for some $a \in (\bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} A_{\lambda})$. `(You could use proper English words to make your argument more readable. )`
>
> Since $a \in (\bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \wedge} A_{\lambda}) \rightarrow a \in A_{\lambda}$ for some $\lambda \in \wedge$. `(This is a mistake. "for some" should be "for every". Your argument breaks down. I would stop reading from here.)`
>
> $(\leftarrow)$ `(This direction is wrong.)`

---

This problem is in Willards, "General Topology." Please let me know if this solution is accurate. `(Not yet.)`

Answer (score 2):

Let $b \in f(\bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \Lambda}A_{\lambda})$, then $b = f(a)$ for some $a \in \bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \Lambda}A_{\lambda}$, i.e. $\forall \lambda \in \Lambda$ $a \in A_{\lambda}$, hence $\forall \lambda \in \Lambda$ $f(a) \in f(A_{\lambda})$. So, $b \in \bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \Lambda}f(A_{\lambda})$. This gives $f(\bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \Lambda}A_{\lambda}) \subseteq \bigcap\limits_{\lambda \in \Lambda}f(A_{\lambda})$.

But the second direction does not work. Imagine $f$ to be constant function, but $A_{\lambda}$ be a partitioning of the domain of $f$. So image of intersection is empty, while intersection of images is not.